# SendMouseClickEvent doesn't work sometimes

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, pixi.js

I'm trying to simulate a click event on a `HTML5` `canvas` using `SendMouseClickEvent`, but even though this works sometimes, sometimes it doesn't. This is the code snippet I'm using to simulate a **click**:

```
browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseMoveEvent(300, 25, false, CefEventFlags.None);
browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(300, 25, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(300, 25, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
```

For example; when I load [this](https://www.goodboydigital.com/runpixierun/) game in `ChromiumWebBrowser`, although it works fine in first 2 scenes where we click on `canvas` to skip the intro, this approach doesn't work in game.
I'm pretty sure it still clicks there but I don't have a clue what's happening here.

Comment: Would you please  add Thread.Sleep method between same click event like below:
browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(300, 25, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(300, 25, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
Let me know is this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: What version are you using? Are you using WinForms, WPF or OffScreen?

Comment: @amaitland I've been using v75.1.142 - WinForms. I've solved this issue by setting  `CefEventFlag.None` to `CefEventFlag.LeftMouseButton`

Answer (score 0):

**To Simulate a Mouse Click (and Move):**

```
// get browser host
var wbHost = chromiumWebBrowser1.GetBrowser().GetHost();

// clicking cordinates
int xPosition = 100;
int yPosition = 300;

// send mouse move event
wbHost.SendMouseMoveEvent(xPosition, yPosition, false, CefEventFlags.None);
Thread.Sleep(50);

// send click
wbHost.SendMouseClickEvent(xPosition, yPosition, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
Thread.Sleep(50);
wbHost.SendMouseClickEvent(xPosition, yPosition, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
```

1 - Sometimes (specially with anti-crawler environments) it's necessary to also mimic the mouse movement. I do it using the method `SendMouseMoveEvent` as shown in the first line.

2 - The clicking occurs at the specified `x` and `y` coordinates, but is very important to know that this coordinates are relative to the browser component window (viewport). So if your web browser component is only `100px` tall and you send a clicking command to `y` coordinate as `150px` the clicking will occur **but outside the web browser**, hence, not in the web page.

3 - One trick to see if the click is really being executed, and where exactly, is change it from `MouseButtonType.Left` to `MouseButtonType.Right`. Doing it, if there is no restrictions on the web page, you will be able to see the "mouse right button menu". If you are clicking outside, chances are that you'll see a "mouse right button menu" on the OS <sup>(Windows here, and I was able to see that I was clicking outside my component with this trick)</sup> .

4 - Also, the delays using `Thread.Sleep(50);` give the component time to execute properly events.